# How to reset counters in a child component in React Native

Tags: react-native, parent-child, state

I have a PlusMinus component whose purpose is to let the user increment or decrement an integer. In my parent component, I loop through several items in a list and provide a PlusMinus counter for each item.

How can I reset all the counters from the parent component?  Most answers to questions like this suggest handling state in the parent, making the child stateless, and passing values to the child via props.  However, when I update those prop values in the parent, the child does not update.  Some answer componentWillReceiveProps.  However, that function is deprecated and I was not able to get it to work anyway.

Here is my component.  It works, except I have no way to reset the counters.  How can I provide a button in my parent that resets all the child counters?

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

import styles from './Styles'

type Props = { k: string, handler: Function, style: Object }
type State = { clicks: Object }

export default class PlusMinus extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state = {
    clicks: {}
  }

  IncrementItem = (k: string) => {

    let clicks = this.state.clicks

    if ('undefined' == typeof this.state.clicks[k]) {
      clicks[k] = 1
    }
    else {
      clicks[k]++
    }

    // A handler passed from the parent that updates persistent values in the parent.
    this.props.handler(k, clicks[k])

    this.setState(
      { clicks: clicks }
    )
  }

  DecreaseItem = (k: string) => {

    let clicks = this.state.clicks

    if ('undefined' == typeof this.state.clicks[k]) {
      clicks[k] = 0
    }
    else if (this.state.clicks[k] > 0) {
      clicks[k]--
    }

    this.props.handler(k, clicks[k])

    this.setState(
      { clicks: clicks }
    )
  }

  Count = (k: string) => {
    let ct = 0

    if ('undefined' !== typeof this.state.clicks[k]) {
      ct = this.state.clicks[k]
      ct = ct++
    }
    return (
      <Text style={styles.counter} id={k}>{ ct }</Text>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <View style={this.props.style}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.plusminus} title='+' onPress={() => this.IncrementItem(this.props.k)}>
          <Text style={styles.pmtxt}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.plusminus} title='-' onPress={() => this.DecreaseItem(this.props.k)}>
          <Text style={styles.pmtxt}>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={[{ 
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          marginLeft: 4,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#aaa',
          width: 40,
          borderRadius: 5
        }]}>{this.Count(this.props.k)}</View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

My handler in the parent component looks like...

```
handler = async (key: string, value: Number) => {
    let object = {}
    let str = await Expo.SecureStore.getItemAsync('clicks')
    if (str) {
      object = JSON.parse(str)
    }
    object[key] = value
    str = JSON.stringify(object)
    Expo.SecureStore.setItemAsync('clicks', str)
  }
```

---

------- UPDATE:  Here is a working example. -------

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

import styles from './Styles'

type Props = { k: string, handler: Function, style: Object, clicks: Number }

export default class PlusMinus extends React.Component<Props> {

  IncrementItem = (k: string) => {
    let clicks = this.props.clicks
    this.props.handler(k, clicks, '++')
  }

  DecreaseItem = (k: string) => {
    let clicks = this.props.clicks
    this.props.handler(k, clicks, '--')
  }

  Count = (k: string) => {
    let ct = 0

    if ('undefined' !== typeof this.props.clicks) {
      ct = this.props.clicks
    }
    return (
      <Text style={styles.counter} id={k}>{ ct }</Text>
    )
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <View style={this.props.style}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.plusminus} title='+' onPress={() => this.IncrementItem(this.props.k)}>
          <Text style={styles.pmtxt}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.plusminus} title='-' onPress={() => this.DecreaseItem(this.props.k)}>
          <Text style={styles.pmtxt}>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={[{ 
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          marginLeft: 4,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#aaa',
          width: 40,
          borderRadius: 5
        }]}>{this.Count(this.props.k)}</View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And a working handler for the parent component...

```
 handler = async (key: string, value: Number, pm: string) => {

    let ct = 1
    let n = this.state.clicks[key]

    if ('++' == pm) {
      ct = n
      ct++
    }
    else {
      ct = 0
      if (n > 0) {
        ct = n
        ct--
      }
    }

    let clicks = this.state.clicks
    clicks[key] = ct

    this.setState({clicks: clicks})
  }
```

And the JSX for the child component within the parent's render...

```
<PlusMinus k={k} clicks={this.state.clicks[k]} style={{
                        flexWrap: 'wrap',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        marginBottom: 0,
                        marginRight: 12,
                        paddingBottom: 0,
                        paddingRight: 5,
                        paddingLeft: 5
                      }} handler={this.handler} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best approach is exactly what you described:
Your parent component should handle the clicks and pass it as props to the child component, where the clicks number comes from the state, something like:

```
state = { clicks: [] }
...
<PlusMinus clicks={this.state.clicks[i]} />
```

Then when you want to reset the clicks, you simply run a loop on this.state.clicks and set all items to 0 (obviously, by calling setState with the new array).
And of course, the child component can be stateless and the increment/decrement functions should move to the parent component.

Comment: Thanks!  It sounds like you're saying I should expect the counters in the child component to update when I change each child's prop values in the parent component.  I don't quite grasp how the child component is able to listen for these changes, but I will give it a shot if this is the typical way to proceed.

Comment: That's how React works. When you change the state, render is recalled and the child components will re-render with the new props. Read about React lifecycle to learn more. Good luck!